# How to add a tag/name when creatng a volume on ec2 using boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I can create a volume using boto using the below code.

But, I need to add a name or tag e.g 'my-tag'.  How do I do that in boto when I create the volume?

```
    import boto
    from boto import ec2
    region_id = boto.ec2.get_region(region_id, aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                                 aws_secret_access_key=self.aws_secret_access_key)
    conn = ec2.connection.EC2Connection(region=region_id, aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                                        aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
    vol = conn.create_volume(gigs, placement)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Name it:  `vol.add_tag("Name","yourName")` Name is just a special case sensitive tag

To Tag it:   `vol.add_tag("tagName","Value")`

From [Boto Documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html) `boto.ec2.ec2object` Section